# Php: Count word appearance of each category from textbox input

Tags: php

I need to count probability of each word against each category. I tried this code, but the result not as my expected. It didn't show the if the count value is 0.

I have 2 table:

- tb_thesis --> id_thesis, title, topics
- tb_words --> id_word, id_thesis, word (this table contains tb_thesis which has been explode into single words)

```
//Count the number of words entered against each category

<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    Input Movie Title : <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check">
</form>

<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $thesis_title = $_POST['title'];
        $exp = explode(" ", $thesis_title);

        for ($x = 0; $x < count($exp); $x++) {
            echo $exp[$x];
            if (isset($exp[$x])) {

                $query = "SELECT c.word, a.topic, count(c.word) AS counter
                          FROM tb_word c, tb_thesis a
                          WHERE c.id_thesis = a.id_thesis 
                          and c.word LIKE '%$exp[$x]%'
                          GROUP BY c.word, a.topic";
                $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db));

                $rows = array();
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    $rows[] = $row;

                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                   $word = $row['word'];
                   echo "<tr><td>{$word}</td>";

                   $topic = $row['topic'];
                   echo "<td>{$topic}</td>";

                   $counter = $row['counter'];
                   echo "<td>{$counter}</td></tr>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Example input : "Prediction Using Naive-Bayes"

Assume that I have 2 topics: Machine Learning, Artificial Intelligence.

I need to count word appearance of each category.

This is the result of that query:

```
word       | topics           | count |
-----------|------------------|-------|
predict    | Machine Learning |  2    |
predict    | Artificial Int   |  1    |
naivebayes | Machine Learning |  1    |
```

the result didn't show the P(naivebayes | artificial intelligence)

**This is the result that I expected**

```
word       | topics           | count |
-----------|------------------|-------|
predict    | Machine Learning |  2    |
predict    | Artificial Int   |  1    |
naivebayes | Machine Learning |  1    |
naivebayes | Artificial Int   |  0    |
```

Can someone help me to get it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this query or understand the logic behind this

```
SELECT t.topic,w.word, 'Naive' as searched_word, COUNT(w.word) as counter 
FROM tb_thesis t 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM tb_word WHERE word LIKE '%Naive%') w on w.id_thesis=t.id_thesis 
GROUP BY t.id_thesis, w.word
```

In your foreach loop, use 'searched_word' instead of 'word' to display in table

Comment: this answer just what i need it, but i change the group by from t.id_thesis to t.topics and it's work for me! I also tried to learn left join, and i just found out it can display the null result. Thank you!